# What is the relationship between a python interpreter and a global environment

Tags: python, conda, environment

There are a lot of good articles explaining why you should use python virtual environments. But what I am not able to find out is whether there is one global environment on my machine, or one per major version of python (e.g. one for python 2 and one for python 3), one per version (one for 3.9, one for 3.10, ...), or even more granular and one global environment for 3.9.7, one for 3.9.8, ... . I just want to understand what context the word "global" is being applied to.

Thank you.

Comment: By way of an example... macOS comes with Python installed. So you could think of that as the "global" version. However, it's not usually up-to-date. You don't need to remove it. In fact, you probably shouldn't. So, download your favourite version of Python and create a virtual environment. Do your development in your VE and leave the default (global) version alone

Comment: Since *"global environment"* isn't an official term, consider adding some example quotes from the articles in question. Presumably, they mean system- or user-level installations of Python, but without context from the articles, this is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

"Global" is not an official term, so I can only guess what these good articles mean by it. My guess is, it's an installation of a particular Python version. So, indeed, you could have 3.9.7 and 3.9.8 global environments.

As for where you can find them on your computer, Windows has the `py` launcher, which can list them. Other platforms might have something like that too.

> py -0
>
> Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
>
> -3.9-64 *
>
> -2.7-64

As you see, I have 2 versions of Python installed. I think these are what you call "global environments".

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter is just one *part* of any Python environment, the library being the other part.

The library itself can be split into two parts: the standard library, defined by the language and required to be present in any environment, and a collection of site packages, which is initially empty but can be added to and deleted from by the maintainer of an environment.

A global environment is really just a standalone Python installation. A virtual environment is basically just a link between the interpreter and standard library (which can be considered immutable and read-only) of some global environment and a private set of site packages.